# Loop Random Number Generation Without Crashing Application Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Currently I am writing a looping animation method. This method generates a new arc4random_uniform and then converts it to a CGFloat. These values are then inserted into the animateWithDuration function as so:

```
func randomAnimationForPostPackets() {
    while true {
    let randomCoordinatesXInt: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(300)
    let randCoordsX = CGFloat(randomCoordinatesXInt)
    let randomCoordinatesYInt: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(300)
    let randCoordsY = CGFloat(randomCoordinatesYInt)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(5, delay: 0, options: [.AllowUserInteraction], animations: {
        self.postPacketView.center.x = randCoordsX
        self.postPacketView.center.y = randCoordsY
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

When attempting to loop this function in a while loop, the application crashes due to the constant generation of random numbers. How would I be able to implement a looped animation based on a new set of random coordinates each time?

Comment: What do you mean by *"the application crashes due to the constant generation of random numbers"*? How do you know? What is the specific error message and stack trace?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by *"a looped animation"*?

Comment: The application CPU usage accelerates to 100% before it can launch. I assume this is due to the constant generation of random numbers.

Comment: There is no loop in this code. Show where you call it in a loop

Comment: Looped animation: I want the method to generate a new set of random coordinates, perform the animation (wait for the animation to complete before generating the next set of random coordinates), and then continue this cycle in an infinite loop without crashing the application.

Comment: Added where the loop should be now.

Comment: You can probably just call this function from the animation's completion closure

Comment: That loop will just call animations as fast as it can. That is why you crash. You will use all CPU and also run out of memory. Get rid of the while and use the completion handler

Answer (score 3):

Using a `while` loop will just call animations as fast as it can using all the CPU and you will eventually run out of memory.
`animateWithDuration` has a `completion` closure that is called when the animation is complete.  Use this to set up the next animation.

```
func randomAnimationForPostPackets() {
    let randomCoordinatesXInt: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(300)
    let randCoordsX = CGFloat(randomCoordinatesXInt)
    let randomCoordinatesYInt: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(300)
    let randCoordsY = CGFloat(randomCoordinatesYInt)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(5, delay: 0, options: [.AllowUserInteraction], animations: { 
        self.postPacketView.center.x = randCoordsX
        self.postPacketView.center.y = randCoordsY
    }) { (finished) in
        self.randomAnimationsPostPacket()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Paulw11 basically nailed it in the comments: Your call to animateWithDuration is async, i.e. it isn't "blocking" your loop for 5 seconds.  Your loop is spinning wicked fast, like, a bajillion times before that first animate even gets a chance.  In fact, I suspect your loop is taking ALL the resources such that the animate never even tries.